# Rigid Body Rotation and Total Kinetic Energy Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I'm trying to solve a rigid body mechanics question. I was told I would be able to solve it WITHOUT integration, but I'm not so sure. The question reads:

**Consider a disk of mass $m$, which is pure  rolling on a flat surface, whose center of mass has a constant speed $v$ and the body has an angular speed $\omega $. Find the total kinetic energy of the upper right quarter of the disk, at some instant.**

I know I have to find the translational and rotational kinetic energy of the quarter disk chunk, and use $m/4$ as opposed to $m$ for the mass. What I'm mainly confused about is finding the center of mass and the moment of inertia of the quarter disk, which I would guess I need to find because the center of mass of the disk is not the center of mass of the quarter disk.

Comment: I think the MoI of the quarter disc is $\frac14$ of the total MoI of the disc. But I'm not sure this can be proved w/o integration.

Comment: You can do it without integration with the information that the center of mass of a half disk is a distance $4R/3\pi$ from the middle of the straight edge. Maybe there’s a clever way to do it without knowing that. I’m not aware of it.

Comment: @Ben51 pointed out in a comment on my earlier answer that not every quadrant of the disk has the same KE.  I revised my earlier answer to address this insight.  Interesting problem!